# Is there a change of tense in the verb in the reported clause when the reporting verb is in the Conditional Perfect?

Tags: indirect-speech, conditional-perfect

Direct reported speech:

> 'I disagree,' John would probably have said.

Indirect reported speech:

> John would probably have said that he **disagrees/disagreed**.

**Which is correct?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the concept of "backshifted past tense" in reported speech applicable to other types of subordinate clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204893/is-the-concept-of-backshifted-past-tense-in-reported-speech-applicable-to-othe) We usually "backshift" in such contexts, so it's *He said his name **was** John* and *John said he **disagreed.*** The "would probably" conditional element of your example makes no difference here.

Comment: So, a perfect conditional is a past tense, whereas a present perfect is not: 'John has just said that he disagrees.' and  not 'John has just said he disagreed.'

Comment: No, it's not that "a perfect conditional is a past tense". Per previous comment, the "would probably" conditional element of your example is irrelevant. What's going on here is called ***backshifting***. That's why we often say *John **said** that he **disagreed*** rather than *...that he **disagrees***. But note that *John would have said that he **was** British* and *...that he **is** British* are both syntactically fine. It's just that idiomatically the backshifted version is the more common choice.